# Kotlin remove noise from audio file

Tags: kotlin

- In my app i have noise remove from audio file which selected from device.
- I tried this but not get output properly but get noisy/currept audio file as output.

```
 private fun noiseRemovalMethod4(inputFilePath: String, outputFilePath: String) {
        val sbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(readFileAsByteArray(File(inputFilePath))).asShortBuffer()
        val audioShorts = ShortArray(sbuf.capacity())
        sbuf.get(audioShorts)

        val audioDoubles = DoubleArray(audioShorts.size)

        for (i in audioShorts.indices) {
            audioDoubles[i] = java.lang.Short.reverseBytes(audioShorts[i]).toDouble() / 0x8000
        }
        val batchArray = audioDoubles.asSequence().chunked(size = 1792)
        val rmsScore = arrayListOf<Double>()
        for (batch in batchArray){
            val sum: Double =  batch.sumByDouble { it * it }
            val rms = Math.sqrt(sum/batch.size)
            rmsScore.add(rms)
        }

        val minrms = 2.2414737665141438E-4

        val dbArray = arrayListOf<Double>()

        rmsScore.forEach {
//                sample -> dbArray.add(20*Math.log10(sample/minrms))
//                sample -> dbArray.add(20 * Math.log10(Math.abs(sample) / 32768))
                sample -> dbArray.add(20 * Math.log10(Math.abs(sample) / 32767.0))
            val db = 20 * Math.log10(Math.abs(sample) / 32767.0)
          }

// in below step generate output file but got noisy/currept audio file as output
//        writeAudioFile(dbArray ,outputFilePath) 
    }
```

Comment: What audio file format do you use to test it? For the `.wav` file the `java.lang.Short.reverseBytes(audioShorts[i])` line could be wrong

Comment: And could you please check that the `writeAudioFile` works fine? To make it, you could just read your audio file, take the `dbArray` and without any manipulations just write it in an output file. After that, you can compare the original file and the result byte-to-byte.

Comment: i have used m4a, mp3, wav

Comment: Yes i also need help to develop manipulations method 
my developed method not give  proper output as i need